# spritekit collision detection inconsistency (failing to get position of both nodes)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

Within didBeginContact function I'm successfully capturing the collision between a horizontal grid line and a circle.

At the collision I can successfully get the position of the circle(head).

```
    if let headBody = contact.bodyB.node as? SnakeBodyUnit {
        print("head position ", headBody.position)
    }
```

This successfully prints out:
head position  (87.536979675293, 267.116882324219)

Now if I try to examine the horizontal line:

```
    if let tripRow = contact.bodyA.node as? HeadTripper {
        print("row position ", tripRow.position)
    }
```

I get the following error:
po tripRow
error: :1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'tripRow'
tripRow

Here is the condition where this detection fires:

```
if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.TripRow && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Head) {
//contact successfully fires
}
```

The HeadTripper class and the SnakeBodyUnit class are both SKNode classes.

Here is the SnakeBodyUnit class:

```
import SpriteKit

class SnakeBodyUnit : SKNode {

    var bodyDir: Direction?
    var id = -1
    var staticIDref = -1
    var partX:CGFloat = -1
    var partY:CGFloat = -1
    var bodyT = -1
    var staticTurn: TurnCrumb?
    var turnRequested = 0
    var requestedTurn: Direction?

    var unitHolder: SKSpriteNode?

    init(size: CGSize, bodyType: Int) {
        super.init()

        bodyT = bodyType

        let reducedSize = size.width

        unitHolder = SKSpriteNode()

        unitHolder!.size = CGSize(width: (size.width), height: (size.height))

        if (bodyT == 0) {
            //head

            unitHolder!.color = UIColor.clearColor()
            //unitHolder!.position = CGPoint(x:xPos, y:yPos);

            let shape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: reducedSize/2)
            shape.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            shape.position = CGPoint(x: reducedSize/2, y: reducedSize/2)
            unitHolder!.addChild(shape)

            self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(reducedSize, reducedSize), center: CGPointMake(reducedSize/2, reducedSize/2))
            self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Head
            self.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.TripRow | ColliderType.TripColumn | ColliderType.Food | ColliderType.Body | ColliderType.WallLeft | ColliderType.WallRight | ColliderType.WallBottom | ColliderType.WallTop | ColliderType.Canvas

        } else if (bodyT == 1) {
            //body part
            self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(reducedSize, reducedSize), center: CGPointMake(reducedSize/2, reducedSize/2))
            self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Body
            self.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
            self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.WallLeft | ColliderType.WallRight | ColliderType.WallBottom | ColliderType.WallTop | ColliderType.BodyStatic


        } else if (bodyT == 2) {
            //static corner
            self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(reducedSize/2, reducedSize/2), center: CGPointMake(reducedSize/2, reducedSize/2))
            self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.BodyStatic
            self.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
            self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        }

        unitHolder!.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.addChild(unitHolder!)

    }
    func updateColor(color: UIColor) {
        unitHolder!.color = color
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        //fatalError("init coder not implemented")
    }
}
```

Here is the HeadTripper class:

```
import SpriteKit

class HeadTripper : SKNode {

    var id = -1
    var rowTripLine: SKSpriteNode?
    var colTripLine: SKSpriteNode?


    init(size: CGSize, rowOrCol: Int) {
    //init(size: CGSize, xPos: Double, yPos: Double, rowOrCol: Int) {
        super.init()
        //row 0
        //col 1

        if (rowOrCol == 0) {
            //row
            rowTripLine = SKSpriteNode()
            rowTripLine!.color = UIColor.redColor()

            //rowTripLine!.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: yPos);
            rowTripLine!.size = CGSize(width: Int(size.width), height: 1)

            //borderLeft!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size, center: CGPointMake(reducedSize/2, reducedSize/2))
            rowTripLine!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: rowTripLine!.size, center: CGPointMake(rowTripLine!.size.width/2, rowTripLine!.size.height/2))
            rowTripLine!.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            rowTripLine!.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.TripRow
            rowTripLine!.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
            rowTripLine!.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

            rowTripLine!.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            self.addChild(rowTripLine!)
        } else {
            //col
            colTripLine = SKSpriteNode()
            colTripLine!.color = UIColor.redColor()

            //colTripLine!.position = CGPoint(x: xPos, y: 0);
            colTripLine!.size = CGSize(width: 1, height: Int(size.height))

            //borderLeft!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size, center: CGPointMake(reducedSize/2, reducedSize/2))
            colTripLine!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: colTripLine!.size, center: CGPointMake(colTripLine!.size.width/2, colTripLine!.size.height/2))
            colTripLine!.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            colTripLine!.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.TripColumn
            colTripLine!.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
            colTripLine!.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

            colTripLine!.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            self.addChild(colTripLine!)
        }

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init coder not implemented")
    }
}
```

I generate the HeadTripper lines like this in the main scene:

```
for var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++ {

    let rowTrip = HeadTripper(size: size, rowOrCol: 0)
    rowTrip.id = i
    rowTrip.position.x = 0
    rowTrip.position.y = CGFloat(yVal)
    self.addChild(rowTrip)

    rowLines.append(CGFloat(rowTrip.position.y))
    CGPathMoveToPoint(linePath, nil, 0, CGFloat(yVal))
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(linePath, nil, CGFloat(theGrid.screenWidth), CGFloat(yVal))
    yVal += (theGrid.snakeHigh + yValPad)

}
```

Here is how the collider types are setup:

```
struct ColliderType {
    static let Head:          UInt32 = 0
    static let Food:          UInt32 = 0b1
    static let Body:          UInt32 = 0b10
    static let BodyStatic:    UInt32 = 0b100
    static let WallLeft:      UInt32 = 0b1000
    static let WallBottom:    UInt32 = 0b10000
    static let WallRight:     UInt32 = 0b100000
    static let WallTop:       UInt32 = 0b1000000
    static let None:          UInt32 = 0b10000000
    static let Canvas:        UInt32 = 0b100000000
    static let TripColumn:    UInt32 = 0b1000000000
    static let TripRow:       UInt32 = 0b10000000000
}
```

The tripRow let setup happens on line 310. On line 309 I can see the contact.bodyA:

```
0x000000012758db20
 {
  NSObject = {
    isa = 0x000000012758db20
  }
  _representedObject = 0x00000001275765a0
  _field = 0x0000000000000000
  _dynamicType = 2
  _world = 0x0000000127761b90
  _joints = 0x0000000127576270 "0 values"
  _inUse = true
  _shapeType = 2
  _radius = 0
  _edgeRadius = 0.0010000000474974513
  _mask = 0x0000000000000000
  _isPinned = false
  _allowsRotation = true
  _postStepBlock = 0x000000019e666c70
}
```

I can also see the contact.bodyA.node:

```
0x00000001275765a0
 {
  UIKit.UIResponder = {...}
}
```

Line 311 never gets called because its in the if condition that isn't passing.

At line 313 I attempt to look at tripRow and get this:

```
(lldb) po tripRow
error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'tripRow'
tripRow
```

It sounds like issue is related to the children within HeadTripper. I have named the children "row" and "col" respectively.

```
print("body A name ", contact.bodyA.node?.name)
let tripRow = contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode
```

This gives a name of "row". Also tripRow now prints out as:

```
(lldb) po tripRow
0x0000000155e737c0
 {
  SpriteKit.SKNode = {...}
}
```

I think this is very close. The problem still exists that the position is not accurate. The y value should be a number like 54 and it is zero:

```
(lldb) po tripRow?.position
(x = 0, y = 0)
```

Comment: contact order is not preserved in sprite kit,  the system is not smart enough to know who contacted who at all times, only that a contact has happened.  There is no guarantee in your code that `bodyA` will always be `HeadTripper`.  You need to set it up so that the body part you are checking is the part you want.  That is why a lot of tutorials out there check the categoryMask first,  and set the lowest values to a variable called First, and higher values to a variable called Second.  Then you can say First is `HeadTripper` or whatever because `HeadTripper` is lower than `SnakeBody`

Comment: my post should be clearer. the collision does happen within this condition:if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.TripRow && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Head) {
//contact successfully fires
}

Comment: It can happen. But im just saying it is not always guarenteed

Comment: ok, but right now I can never get the reference to the headtripper position while I can always get the reference to the other circle/head node.

Comment: can you show how you define collider type,  I wanna make sure it is accurate

Comment: added the ColliderType struct to the post.

Comment: hmm,  could you clean your project,  then show the whole chunk of code  involving the tripRow variable  and mark the line it is failing on,  I just do not see it anywhere that it would be failing

Comment: by clean, I mean clean the project with CMD + Shift + K,  so that we know the error message is pointing to the correct line

Comment: i added some more context after cleaning the build to the post. you can see what prints out for the body and node which ideally would let me access the tripRow reference. the error message is the same when looking at tripRow.

Comment: wait,  if the if condition on 310 is failing and 311 is the print that never gets called,  why are you trying to read tripRow on 313,  isn't that outside the scope of the if statement

Comment: yeah, this is the heart of the problem. why does this condition fail?              if let tripRow = contact.bodyA.node as? HeadTripper { //does not fire }

Comment: it is failing because bodyA.node is not headtripper,  give all your node children a name,  and do print(contact.bodyA.node.name) to see what the name is

Comment: thanks. i named the children. i'm now getting a non nil reference to tripRow. there is still a nagging issue the the y position is returning 0 when it should be a higher number. i could possibly refactor this so that i'm just creating the HeadTripper without children. thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: fix also the issue I first mentioned,  that was probably causing the debugging issue you began with, and just didn't know because the results may have varried

Comment: i'm definitely going to refactor this. the multiple children seem to be causing issues. this should not return (0,0) but it does:                                         (lldb) po contact.bodyA.node?.position
(x = 0, y = 0)                                                                                                this seems bug like if the node is clearly greater than 0 but returns 0 in debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by having just 1 SKSpriteNode referenced in the HeadTripper SKNode class instead of 2.